Use creations made by AI tools
Do we have the right to use an image or text or other generated by Google Bard / Gemini / other known AI tool and put it on our site for example?
or do you have to pay for the tool like microsoft / google?
This is for personal website..., non-commercial purposes.

What does your license say?
You agreed to a license by using the AI. That license prescribes your allowable uses of the product of the usage.
